# How to retrieve calendar event attendees

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API and [quick start code for Python](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python).  The quick start code works, however when I try to retrieve calendar event attendees, I get a "key error".  The original code for retrieving calendar events is

```
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])
```

I added attendees like this:

```
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'],event['attendees'])
```

'attendees' is a valid term to use as it is listed in the [Python API reference](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.events.html).

Any thoughts why retrieving attendees doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Not every event does have **attendees**. so If an event doesn't have any attendees, the response object won't have an **attendees** attribute.
you can use

```
print(start, event['summary'], event.get('attendees', []))
```

instead of

```
print(start, event['summary'], event['attendees'])
```

and it will set an empty list when no `attendees` exists